# What does the hat "Where in the World?" signify?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2016

Apologies if this is off-topic, but I've just been awarded a hat called "Where in the World?".

Apparently it's a secret hat (*shhh!*) - does anyone know how I might have earned it?

Comment: Find here [All hats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288271/winter-bash-2016-all-hats).

Comment: Ssh! We're a covert group infiltrating SO's reviewing system... ;-)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

There is a list of [secret hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288284/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange. Apparently, this hat is awarded

> For participating on a site on December 21.

The hat is already awarded now, because

> it's already December 21st in the eastern-most time zones of the world (UTC+14).

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem right. I earned the hat before it was December 21 either in Stack Overflow's UTC time or in my local time. It wasn't even December 21 in UTC time when you posted this answer.

Comment: There's a reason that this badge is called *where in the World*.

Comment: Ruining the secrets @Glorfindel I see how you are!

Comment: @bluefeet Is the true secret that this is where we can find Carmen Sandiego?

Comment: All I can provide by way of backup is that I was just awarded this, on a site where my profile showed no activity of any kind on my part in the last week. So at the least it has to be something that isn't logged on the user profile page.

Comment: It is a special anniversary hat from a Mayan.

Comment: "The badge" is awarded? Wouldn't it be "The hat"?

Comment: @EMBarbosa thanks, I keep making that mistake.

Answer (score 13):

Well it's secret so we can't tell you how you got it.  You'd have to do some investigating to figure out what might have triggered it.

Comment: Is the accepted explanation (winter solstice) the correct one? I got it after opening SO in a different country than normal and thought that was the secret

Comment: Nice try @Pekka웃 we haven't confirmed any secret hats...yet! :)

Answer (score 11):

LOOK AT THIS HAT!!!  THIS HAT IS AMAZING!!!

[image]

Comment: I'll take my downvotes with pride!  This hat is flipping amazing!

Comment: I don't know why this doesn't have more downvotes! This is amazing :D

Comment: @MarounMaroun and a delete flag ;)