# I got a secret hat. Can I find out what for?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

I've just got a [secret hat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280283/whats-a-secret-hat). Will it ever be disclosed **to me** why?

Is it a guessing game to the very end (and beyond)?

[image]

**CLARIFICATIONS**:

1. My question is not about *any* particular hat.  I was wondering, whether once awarded, the secret is still kept from the winners.
2. The above image is **not** a winter bash hat.  This is (as close as I was able to find) a vision of "secret hat" itself.

Comment: What's the *name* of this hat? I haven't seen it before.

Comment: Is this a real Winter Bash hat?

Comment: @PM77-1 That's awarded for voting during the winter solstice

Comment: Where in the World is explained [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339920/what-does-the-where-in-the-world-signify).

Comment: But my question (and Panda's) remains: is that picture you posted a real Winterbash hat?

Comment: @Glorfindel - No, it is not. The image is from here: https://www.dreamstime.com/royalty-free-stock-images-question-mark-hat-image28576669

Comment: @PM77-1: I guess you are confusing folks with that image a lot...

Comment: Yea, I thought that was a newly discovered hat ...

Comment: You can post an image of the actual hat you're talking about -- https://i.stack.imgur.com/8n606.png

Comment: Usually all secret hats are kept secret until the end of WinterBash, when their official triggers are usually posted in the annual secret hats post on Meta.se

Comment: [Apparently](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339922/2055998), to the end.

Comment: The "hat" in your question would make a nice secret hat for next year: It could be completely randomly awarded so that the community goes mad while trying to find out how to get it.

Comment: @PM77-1, your question is similar [my question on Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288452/271772) :)

Comment: @Honk or you could get a secret hat for getting a secret hat. Hatception.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

It will not be disclosed to you officially. However, there's already a [list of secret hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288284/295232) and a [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50144/ye-olde-hat-shoppe) dedicated to finding out the triggers.

Comment: what if there's no reason and it's totally random just to mess with you

Comment: No. [Random](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/9314/random) has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 13):

No. It's a secret. Best you can do is try and relate the hat to actions you have done and then have someone replicate what you suspect and see if they get the hat.