# How are some users getting the Bûche de Noël hat before December 25th?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

Yes, I know it's 24th December for me, but at some place in world it might be 25th December, but I am talking about my time zone. A user from my timezone has already got Bûche de Noël hat which should be only unlocked by doing some activity on 25th December; how come he got this hat?

It's even written in the hat description:

> #### Bûche de Noël
>
> ask, answer, or vote on December 25th

For proof, see this [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6295641/karthick-nagarajan#winter-bash).

Just wondering is this a bug or what?

Comment: Downvoters please explain why you just gave dv even in 30 sec without reading my question.. I am sure there is no hidden hat for down-voting any question without reading the question.

Comment: I actually received this hat when it was December 23rd in my locale, a good 12 hours away from December 24th, and a *long* time away from December 25th. I thought it was strange, too, but [we've seen this happen before](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339920/what-does-the-hat-where-in-the-world-signify/339925#339925).

Comment: Clearly the downvoters just hate hats!

Comment: i think yes as i just got 2 dv in less then 20 sec..no one can read my question in that such speed.

Comment: Well, I can easily read a couple short paragraphs of text in under 20 seconds. But remember, it's Meta. People downvote for [all kinds of reasons](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340169/how-long-do-hats-usually-take-to-be-awarded?cb=1#comment424888_340169).

Comment: I got it a few mins ago, ant it's *5 in the morning*.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: *[Got “Bûche de Noël” hat on Dec 24 instead of “Have a little Dreidel”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288735)*

Comment: It took me WELL UNDER 20 seconds to read your question fully.  I didn't downvote though.  Although I think a hidden hat for downvoting a question without reading it would be a FANTASTIC idea.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Most date-based hats have a [rather large window](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159748/295232) in which they are awarded. You just have to remember that if it's December 25th *anywhere in the world*, your actions qualify for the hat.

The exact details for Bûche de Noël have [just been published](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288738/295232) by a Stack Overflow developer:

> Bûche de Noël is awarded between 10am UTC on the 24th (12am of the 25th in some Pacific islands) and 11:59am UTC on the 26th (11:59pm of the 25th in some other Pacific islands).

Comment: then all the user should get this hat, right?

Comment: @Leothelion yes, they do.

Comment: Thank you for useful links but it was a bug as SO developer mentioned.. bdw i tried on net before asking question but did not find so asked here. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Leothelion no, there was no bug for 'Bûche de Noël'. The bug was for 'I have a little Dreidel'.

Comment: then why i and  you did not get that hat??

Comment: I just got 'I have a little Dreidel' one minute ago. (Actually, I got 15 of them.) These have been rewarded retroactively, it seems.

Comment: same here..i got that too..so should i wait for that??

Comment: Have you already voted (on the main site) **today**? You could have got the Dreidel for voting *yesterday* (after 10am UTC).

Comment: no i just got now..but not the one which we should get on 25th..bdw thank you for your answer. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131410/discussion-between-glorfindel-and-leo-the-lion).

Comment: In 24h format, does 12am mean 00:00 or 12:00?

Comment: It means 00:00.

Comment: @Glorfindel I delete my comment. There was maybe some lag/timeout

Comment: I earned both Bûche de Noël and Little Dreidel in other SE sites, even in JST already goes above 12:00 am (1:07 am now). It seems that Bûche de Noël follows December 25th on local time, and Dreidel follows UTC.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto no, it's based on UTC. Check the [linked answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288738/295232) for the exact details for both badges.